# PHP create folder, upload file and allow delete file best security measure

Tags: php

I am developing an application that allows users to upload images. The script creates multiple sizes of the image and stores them in folders with a session ID e.g. /uploads/skj28cnkjck783wo/thumbnails before renaming the folder to a unique name once the user hits submit/next/go.

I need to allow users to have the ability to remove individual files but wondering what the best secure way of doing this would be. If I base the delete off the session ID surely users would be able to change this and remove files that don't belong to them.

I was thinking I could store user information and the object reference in a table and do a lookup to ensure that user has access to remove that file or store the files in a folder with the user ID which is unique based on DB entry but wondering what the experts think. I have done some Google searching but all have flaws.

I am running IIS7 as the web server.

Thanks

Comment: Is user uploading the file via ftp? How can he get access to other users' files?

Comment: Uploading through a PHP form. The page outputs files in the users directory with a delete button for each. The delete button submits a request to the server to remove the selected file. I guess a user could manipulate this by changing the value before submitting to the server.

Comment: You don't have to allow him access to other folders, just check his input before deletion. Eg. it must not contain slashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is you who manipulates the files, not the user himself.

The user gives the file name (or perhaps some file id) in his GET or POST request.

1. Disallow relative paths by rejecting all inputs that contain slashes. It's easy if you don't allow subfolders.
2. If you allow subfolders, reject all that have ../ etc.
3. You can keep files by changing their names (like flickr does), and keeping data of the filename (to show to the user) and the owner. If owner and user do not match, reject.

Answer (score 1):

Try to store relations "userName(or userID)"->"UserFile" in separate table. This is the best secure way, bacause OS (Windows in your case) can detect only one user - owner of web service (IIS or Apache, etc.)

Comment: I was hoping I could set user permissions to the uploaded files but you are right, can't do it on windows.

Comment: The best secure way for all scripts - create users & usersPermissions tables. Try to store all users permissions in high-level structures. This is right way for all OS (Windows, Linux, ets.)